# What prepositions should I use with "want" in the following sentences?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, idiomatic-language, collocations

I just cannot decide whether to use "for" or "in" in the following examples.

> We want two engineers (for / in) the project.

> We want two violin players (for / in) the show.

> Musicians are wanted (for / in) the New Year's Celebration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can want a person "for" an activity, so "for" is correct in all three sentences.

Also, a person can appear "in" a performance, so "in" is correct for the second and third sentences. However, a person is generally not "in" a project, so that preposition wouldn't work for the first sentence.

Note that some other prepositions may be possible, too. For example, a person can be "on" a project, so that preposition could work for the first sentence.

Comment: Is there any difference in meaning when using "for" or "in" for the second and third sentences?

Comment: If you say "in", then the person will actually be in the show / celebration. If you say "for", then the person wouldn't necessarily be in the performance; he or she might simply record some background music for it, for example.

Comment: So, "Musicians are wanted for the performance." could mean that the musicians could play music in the background instead of showing up on the stage. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The preposition "for" doesn't really indicate how the musicians will participate.

Comment: Thank you for you time and help. Have a nice day.

Comment: If I say *I want two violin players **for** the show.*  I am saying that I need to find two violin players to appear in my show.  If I say, *I want two violin players **in** the show.* I am indicating that two violin players should appear in the show.  Not one, not three, but two.